# How do I link to another php page?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a footer navigation inside an unordered list.

How do I link these navigation links to the pages in my WordPress site? I have tried the following code but it doesn't work.

```
 <ul>
     <li><a href="<?php echo 'front-page.php'; ?>" class="footer-link-text">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="<?php echo 'index.php'; ?>" class="footer-link-text">Portfolio</a></li>
     <li><a href="<?php echo 'page.php'; ?>" class="footer-link-text">About Me</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You link the same way you would link to a html page. You don't need to use php to echo the php file. You can just write it in html.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to  use

```
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $post_id );?>">Pagename</a>
```

This way the link stays consistent, even if the slug changes - if you want to echo home_url() or  get_permalink( get_option( 'page_for_posts' ) ) for other content